# Lookup delay when first calling an NDK function?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have read that the first time you call an NDK function from Java, Android must search the shared libraries for a matching function signature. When I first call a custom NDK function from Java, there is a noticeable delay (around ~0.2s) and the following debug output appears in logcat:

```
+++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'myNdkFunction' (wrong CL)
+++ not scanning '/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so' for 'myNdkFunction' (wrong CL)
```

As this function call happens during touch events, it means the user sees a small delay when they first use my app. Is there a way to force Android to find my NDK function in advance to avoid this delay? I could call my function with dummy parameters somewhere but I'd need to clutter up my function definition to allow such parameters, which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JNI's RegisterNatives function. Here's an example of using it on Android:

http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/25/boosting-android-performance-using-jni/

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I'm thinking that calling the function with dummy values is cleaner now compared this.